# How to send session variables through response redirect in node js express

Tags: node.js, express, session

I want to send some session variable through response redirect in my ejs views

```
router.get('/contact', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.session.enquiry);

    res.render('contact', {
        enquiry: req.session.enquiry
    });
});
```

I want to pass session data here:

```
router.post('/sendresponse', function(req, res) {
    req.session.enquiry = 'sent message';
    res.redirect('/contact');
});
```

And display it in my view like:

```
<div class="mail_form">
    <% if (enquiry) { %>
        <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= enquiry %></div>
    <% } %>
</div>
```

Any idea how to achieve this ,and no i don't want to use flash or something else

Comment: So what is your problem exactly?

Comment: i am unable to send session variables through redirect

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem in my app.  Did you wire your session correctly?  Did you see the output from your `console.log`?  Where is the error message or no message at all?  Without exact descriptions, I can not help.